# Stored procedure some inserts not working properly

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_TRX_BUCKET`(
IN sMethod          varchar(30),
IN sCode            varchar(25),
IN sName            varchar(100),
IN sIsActive        varchar(2),
IN sIsSystem        varchar(2),
IN sBy              varchar(10),
IN bType            varchar(6),
IN ReplicateChoice  varchar(20),
IN Adjust           varchar(10),
IN Percentage       varchar(3),
OUT Result          varchar(30),
OUT Message         varchar(30)

)
BEGIN
 DECLARE _statement VARCHAR(8000);
    IF sMethod = 'UPDATE_BUCKET' THEN

                  UPDATE  stkm_pricebucket
                  SET   bucket_isactive =  sIsActive,
                        bucket_issystem = sIsSystem,
                        modifiedby = sBy,
                        modifieddt = NOW(),
                        bucket_desc = sName
                        WHERE bucket_code =  sCode ;

                   SELECT '00000' INTO Result;
                   SELECT  'Success Update' INTO Message;

    END IF;
    
    IF sMethod = 'ADD_BUCKET' THEN
            
            IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT bucket_code FROM stkm_pricebucket WHERE bucket_code = sCode) THEN
                INSERT INTO stkm_pricebucket (bucket_code, bucket_desc, bucket_isactive, bucket_issystem, createdby, createddt)
                VALUES (sCode, sName, sIsActive, sIsSystem, sBy, NOW());
                
                SELECT '00000' INTO Result;
                SELECT 'Success Update' INTO Message;
            
            ELSE
                SELECT 'DUPLICATE BUCKET CODE' INTO Result;
            END IF;         
    END IF;
    
    IF sMethod = 'ADD_BUCKET_DDL' THEN
            
            IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT cd_cdcode FROM stkc_codedesc WHERE cd_cdcode = sCode) THEN
                INSERT INTO stkc_codedesc (cd_cdtype, cd_cdcode, cd_cddesc, createdby, createddt, recstatus)
                VALUES (bType, sCode, sName, sBy, NOW(), sIsActive);
                
                SELECT '00000' INTO Result;
                SELECT 'Success Update' INTO Message;
            ELSE
                SELECT 'DUPLICATE BUCKET CODE' INTO Result;
            END IF;
    END IF;
    
    IF sMethod = 'ADD_BUCKET_SPUOM' THEN
            
            IF Adjust = 'MarkUp' THEN
            
                INSERT INTO stkm_stockpricesuom (spu_pricebucket, spu_stockcode, spu_uomcode, recstatus, createdby, createddt, modifiedby, modifieddt, spu_unitprice, spu_factor, spu_effdate)
                SELECT sCode, spu_stockcode, spu_uomcode, recstatus, createdby, createddt, modifiedby, modifieddt, round((spu_unitprice + (spu_unitprice*Percentage/100)),2), spu_factor, spu_effdate 
                FROM stkm_stockpricesuom where spu_pricebucket=(SELECT bucket_code from stkm_pricebucket WHERE bucket_desc=ReplicateChoice);

                SELECT '00000' INTO Result;
                SELECT 'Success Update' INTO Message;
                
            ELSEIF Adjust = 'MarkDown' THEN
            
                INSERT INTO stkm_stockpricesuom (spu_pricebucket, spu_stockcode, spu_uomcode, recstatus, createdby, createddt, modifiedby, modifieddt, spu_unitprice, spu_factor, spu_effdate)
                SELECT sCode as spu_pricebucket, spu_stockcode, spu_uomcode, recstatus, createdby, createddt, modifiedby, modifieddt, round((spu_unitprice - (spu_unitprice*Percentage/100)),2) as spu_unitprice, spu_factor, spu_effdate 
                FROM stkm_stockpricesuom where spu_pricebucket=(SELECT bucket_code from stkm_pricebucket WHERE bucket_desc=ReplicateChoice);
                
                SELECT '00000' INTO Result;
                SELECT 'Success Update' INTO Message;
                
            ELSE 
            
                INSERT INTO stkm_stockpricesuom (spu_pricebucket, spu_stockcode, spu_uomcode, recstatus, createdby, createddt, modifiedby, modifieddt, spu_unitprice, spu_factor, spu_effdate)
                SELECT sCode as spu_pricebucket, spu_stockcode, spu_uomcode, recstatus, createdby, createddt, modifiedby, modifieddt, spu_unitprice, spu_factor, spu_effdate 
                FROM stkm_stockpricesuom where spu_pricebucket=(SELECT bucket_code from stkm_pricebucket WHERE bucket_desc=ReplicateChoice);

                SELECT '00000' INTO Result;
                SELECT 'Success Update' INTO Message;           
    
            END IF;
    END IF;

    
    IF sMethod = 'ADD_BUCKET_CIP' THEN
            
            IF Adjust = 'MarkUp' THEN

                INSERT INTO stkc_chargeitemprices (cip_pricebucket, cip_chargecategory, cip_code, recstatus, createdby, createddt, modifiedby, modifieddt, cip_unitprice, cip_effdate)
                SELECT sCode, cip_chargecategory, cip_code, recstatus, createdby, createddt, modifiedby, modifieddt, round((cip_unitprice + (cip_unitprice*Percentage/100)),3), cip_effdate
                FROM stkc_chargeitemprices WHERE cip_pricebucket=(SELECT bucket_code from stkm_pricebucket WHERE bucket_desc=ReplicateChoice);
            
                SELECT '00000' INTO Result;
                SELECT 'Success Update' INTO Message;
            
            ELSEIF Adjust = 'MarkDown' THEN

                INSERT INTO stkc_chargeitemprices (cip_pricebucket, cip_chargecategory, cip_code, recstatus, createdby, createddt, modifiedby, modifieddt, cip_unitprice, cip_effdate)
                SELECT sCode, cip_chargecategory, cip_code, recstatus, createdby, createddt, modifiedby, modifieddt, round((cip_unitprice - (cip_unitprice*Percentage/100)),3) as cip_unitprice, cip_effdate
                FROM stkc_chargeitemprices WHERE cip_pricebucket=(SELECT bucket_code from stkm_pricebucket WHERE bucket_desc=ReplicateChoice);
    
                SELECT '00000' INTO Result;
                SELECT 'Success Update' INTO Message;
            
            ELSE
            
                INSERT INTO stkc_chargeitemprices (cip_pricebucket, cip_chargecategory, cip_code, recstatus, createdby, createddt, modifiedby, modifieddt, cip_unitprice, cip_effdate)
                SELECT sCode, cip_chargecategory, cip_code, recstatus, createdby, createddt, modifiedby, modifieddt, cip_unitprice, cip_effdate
                FROM stkc_chargeitemprices WHERE cip_pricebucket=(SELECT bucket_code from stkm_pricebucket WHERE bucket_desc=ReplicateChoice);
    
                SELECT '00000' INTO Result;
                SELECT 'Success Update' INTO Message;

            END IF;
    END IF;
END
```

I have a webapp where users can store prices in pricebuckets. For any given pricebucket, there will be its associated items (stock_codes) and prices (unitprices). So for example, PRICE1 will have a bunch of rows of items with its prices, PRICE2 will have its own and so on.

I need help with this stored procedure. When I call the procedure through the webapp, inserts should occur 5 times, but only the first 3 are successful (UPDATE_BUCKET, ADD_BUCKET, ADD_BUCKET_DDL). The remaining 2 display "successes" (SELECT INTO Result and Message work correctly) but the data is never inserted (ADD_BUCKET_SPUOM, ADD_BUCKET_CIP). I can confirm the required variables are also being sent within the logs the webapp (sMethod, sCode, Adjust, Percentage, ReplicateChoice). What's wrong with my SQL?

Some more notes:

- Its ok for percentage to be varchar, sql automatically casts it as int, so thats not the problem
- ReplicateChoice is case-insensitive, doesnt matter if its all caps or not
- If I perform the insert statements on their own, it works just fine. It just doesn't work when the procedure is called

Really lost here, i don't see anything wrong with the sql. I'm using MySQL Server v8.0.16 with MySQL Workbench

Comment: *What's wrong with my SQL?* Check separately does SELECT part of according INSERT returns any row.

Comment: SELECT 'PRICE5', spu_stockcode, spu_uomcode, recstatus, createdby, createddt, modifiedby, modifieddt, round((spu_unitprice + (spu_unitprice*'5'/100)),2), spu_factor, spu_effdate 
FROM stkm_stockpricesuom where spu_pricebucket=(SELECT bucket_code from stkm_pricebucket WHERE bucket_desc='Low');

Comment: INSERT INTO stkm_stockpricesuom (spu_pricebucket, spu_stockcode, spu_uomcode, recstatus, createdby, createddt, modifiedby, modifieddt, spu_unitprice, spu_factor, spu_effdate)
    SELECT 'PRICE5', spu_stockcode, spu_uomcode, recstatus, createdby, createddt, modifiedby, modifieddt, round((spu_unitprice + (spu_unitprice*'5'/100)),2), spu_factor, spu_effdate 
    FROM stkm_stockpricesuom where spu_pricebucket=(SELECT bucket_code from stkm_pricebucket WHERE bucket_desc='Cash');

Comment: The select and insert statements performed in isolation work fine,  the pricebucket gets added as expected. It doesn't work when called in a procedure for some reason. btw apologies for the wall of text, not sure how to add code blocks in comments 

Comment: No-no, execute them in the procedure (instead of INSERT), call procedure from CLI and see the output. If all data shown is correct then execute original SP from CLI and check the result.

Comment: Check out this link here: https://imgur.com/a/cQd8CyR Looks like its waiting for some kind of input? not sure what to input there

Comment: Of course, it waits for final `;`.

Comment: oh yeah ur right woops. strange thing, it only returns 1 affected row: https://imgur.com/a/mHzjC3m this is how it looks like it my workbench: https://imgur.com/a/JvFrICQ

Comment: OK, I found the problem... I was sending the wrong parameters...